# Does a fitnesse slim tests summary table exist?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am looking at using slim for my test of CSharp code.

And I am wondering if there exist a slim page summary table, that could contain a summary of the tests on a page.  Much like the fit.summary text table, adds a summary for the fit test on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add comments to describe each test by using comment table

http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.CommentTables

Answer (score 0):

Slim does not have a summary table.